# Win-win situation

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, anglicismes

> Definition of win-win : advantageous or satisfactory to all parties involved

- a win-win situation

- a win-win deal

Source : https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/win-win

> We think that in many ways this is a *win-win situation*.
>
> Nous pensons qu’à bien des égards, il s’agit d’une *situation gagnant-gagnant*.

J'ai entendu l'emploi de *situation gagnant-gagnant*. Mais pourquoi pas gagnante-gagnante vu que situation est un substantif féminin ?

Peut-on employer situation **gagnant-gagnant** ou faut-il l'éviter (anglicisme) et utiliser une autre tournure (p.ex. **situation avantageuse**) ? L'expression même est-elle comprehensible par ceux qui ne connaissent pas d'anglais ?

En outre, **win-win** est-il utilisé en français ?

Comment: *gagnant-gagnant* en tant qu'adjectif est "souvent" invariable. Mais je ne l'ai jamais entendu sous sa forme féminine. Cependant, on peut remplacer "il s'agit d'une situation gagnant-gagnant" par "chacun y trouve son compte".

Comment: accorder en genre suppose que l'on connaisse celui des protagonistes, par exemple `un accord entre un état (m) et une entreprise (f) est gagnant-gagnante`  mais ça sonne très mal à l'oreille.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> L'expression même est-elle compréhensible par ceux qui ne connaissent
>   pas d'anglais ?

Oui entre autres parce que la morphologie de ce calque de l'anglo-américain (1990, DHLF) se rapproche de celle de la locution proverbiale *[donnant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donnant) donnant* en français...

> Peut-on employer situation gagnant-gagnant ou faut-il l'éviter
>   (anglicisme) et utiliser une autre tournure (p.ex. situation
>   avantageuse) ?

On a le choix et on peut certainement l'employer si on la considère [acceptable](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4389), comme on l'a étayé au lexique usuel dans une autre réponse. Autrement on peut choisir une formulation avec *tout le monde...* (que *tout le monde y gagne, est gagnant*) ou *...pour tous* (que *c'est avantageux, favorable ou profitable pour tous*) ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4389)) [etc](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31632/win-win-situation#comment64996_31632).. Donc oui la *situation avantageuse* (*pour tous*) est utile...

Comment: @dimitris Merci ! C'est votre choix mais je trouve plus logique de lire l'autre réponse avant celle-ci. L'autre réponse contient l'information concernant l'invariabilité de l'expression (Larousse en ligne et mon commentaire) et la mienne répond autour de ça. N'hésitez pas à inverser votre sélection. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Gagnant-gagnant, qui est effectivement la traduction parfaite de win-win, est invariable [si j'en crois le Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/gagnant-gagnant/186402)

Selon moi cette expression représente simplement une situation où chacun des protagoniste est gagnant, peu importe le genre de ces protagonistes ou du nom dont  gagnant-gagnant est l'adjectif, donc :

> Une situation gagnant-gagnant
>
> Un accord gagnant-gagnant
>
> Des accords gagnant-gagnant

J'imagine que pour le style ou mettre l'accent sur le genre ou le nombre des protagonistes dans certains cas on pourrait abuser le mot, mais ça ne serait donc pas correct.

Comment: Voir aussi [ceci](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=gagnant-gagnant&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) qui fait certainement autorité. Merci !